# Opposite condition producing required results in If Else statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Supposing I have the following array

```
[Agent - 134] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:03:33.089210
                    [1] => CONNECT
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:03:55.053394
                    [1] => COMPLETEAGENT
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:07:29.913989
                    [1] => CONNECT
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:07:56.693848
                    [1] => COMPLETECALLER
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:09:02.989649
                    [1] => CONNECT
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:09:35.608860
                    [1] => COMPLETEAGENT
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:11:56.564747
                    [1] => CONNECT
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:12:25.979910
                    [1] => COMPLETEAGENT
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:20:15.130092
                    [1] => CONNECT
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-07-14 12:20:45.843112
                    [1] => COMPLETEAGENT
                )

        )
```

And I am trying to calculate the difference between the events. The condition for a complete event is if the previous array's second element is a `CONNECT` and the next array's second element is either `COMPLETEAGENT` or `COMPLETECALLER`. I have written the following code to loop through where for testing purposes my If statement should fulfill the condition yet its the `else` that works which leads me to believe there might by something wrong in my syntax for the comparison which I'm unsure of.

```
foreach ($ttt_array as $tKey => $value) {
        $ttt_total = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($value);
        ) {
            if (($value[$i][1] === "CONNECT" && $value[$i + 1][1] === "COMPLETEAGENT") || ($value[$i][1] === "CONNECT" && $value[$i + 1][1] === "COMPLETECALLER")) {
                $i+=1;
                echo $i;
            } else {

                $srtTime = strtotime($value[$i][0]);
                echo "Start-Time" . $srtTime . "<BR>";
                $endTime = strtotime($value[$i + 1][0]);
                echo "End-Time" . $endTime . "<BR>";
                $interval = $endTime - $srtTime;
                echo "Interval" . $interval . "<BR>";
                $ttt_total += $interval;
                $i+=2;
            }
        }
        $ttl_talk_total[$tKey] = timeConverter($ttt_total);
    }
```

Where `$ttt_array` is the array show above. What is incorrect about the if statement?

Comment: use == sign for if statement

Comment: `===` is use-able, [php.net/operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) - It checks for type as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"COMPELETEAGENT" <== Is this the error?
"COMPELETECALLER" <== Also this